# SQL in Excel VBA Syntax

Tags: sql, excel, vba, select

I am trying to write a CASE WHEN  THEN  ELSE  END equivalent in a VBA ODBC connection that queries another excel spreadsheet. I have tried everything and I can only get this to successfully query the spreadsheet:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT Data$.CALC_POST_PERIOD='201211' FROM Data$ Data$
```

The result is when the condition is true it returns `-1` when false it returns `0`

How can I customize this?

I'm trying to do something like this

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Data$.CALC_POST_PERIOD='201211' THEN 'CURR_MONTH' ELSE NULL END
```

but this gives me an error - mismatch

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work for you

```
"SELECT [Items], " _
"IFF([CALC_POST_PERIOD] = '201211' , 'CURR_MONTH' , '') as NewColumn 
FROM [Data$]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just test for TRUE or FALSE after you run the query.

```
If rs.Fields(0).Value Then
    sReturn = "CURR_MONTH"
Else
    sReturn = vbNullString
End If
```

If it's a function, then assign sReturn to the function name.  The Else part isn't really necessary as long as sReturn hasn't been set to something else previously, but I included it here for clarity.  Also assumed your CommandText is for a recordset variable named 'rs'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SWITCH function:

```
SELECT SWITCH(Data$.CALC_POST_PERIOD='201211', 'CURR_MONTH', TRUE, NULL)
```